# почему не работает плавная прокрутка?

Tags: html, прокрутка

на сайте єсть якорь(штук 10)плавная прокрутка реализована вот так:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
```

на пк все работает хорошо,но на телефонах нет,почему?
https://hifest.github.io/portfolio/
сам сайт

Comment: Что значит на телефонах не работет? HTML работает не на телефоне, и не на компьютере. HTML работает в браузере... Какой браузер, какая версия?

Comment: извинаюсь,не подумал што написал safari самая новая версия

Comment: Safari и Internet Explorer (все версии на текущий момент) не поддерживают `scroll-behavior`

Comment: спасибо)))))))))